# pointed object lost its field

Tags: c++

I am trying to construct a simple linked list, using a pointer pointing to the next insertion location, and add a node one by one.

```
Tnode* NULL_cp = 0;
struct Tnode{
 string word;
 Tnode* left;
 Tnode* right;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){
 int n = 0;
 Tnode head;
 head.word = "the head";
 head.left = NULL_cp;
 head.right = NULL_cp;
 Tnode* insertP = &head;
 while(n<argc-1){
  Tnode node;
  node.word = argv[n+1];
  node.left = insertP;
  node.right = NULL_cp;
  insertP->right = &node;
  insertP = &node;
  cout << "inside loop: " << insertP->word <<  endl;
  n++;
 }
 cout << "outside loop: the word is " << insertP->word << endl;
}
```

the output is

```
inside loop: hello
outside loop: the word is
```

if I typed in ***a.out hello***. the part that confused me is that after one loop, the insertP should be pointing at the newly inserted node that has the the word ***hello***, but it printed out nothing even though inside the loop it printed out ***hello***, any idea why? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's minimize the problem:

```
while(n<argc-1)
{
   Tnode node;
   //...
}
```

When `node` goes out of scope, so does its `std::string` member. You'll have dangling pointers to nodes in your tree. Inside the loop it works because the object is still alive. Outside... not so much.

Use dynamic allocation:

```
while(n<argc-1){
  Tnode* node = new Tnode;
  node->word = argv[n+1];
  node->left = insertP;
  node->right = NULL_cp;
  insertP->right = node;
  insertP = node;
  cout << "inside loop: " << insertP->word <<  endl;
  n++;
}
```

And don't forget to `delete` at the end.